# MVC Razor Ajax Form Submit giving 'unexpexted token u'

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is a MVC VB.NET Razor application. I have a partial view which loads in the bottom of a parent view. And in that partial view I have buttons that when click fire a popup dialog modal window which has a partial view attached to it. The user is supposed to be able to edit the form then click update and the information is then posted to the controller. However I am getting the below error message on submit.

[image]

I followed the blog [here](http://ricardocovo.com/) to get everything wired up. When the update button is clicked there error is occuring here:

[image]

Below is the PartialView that contains the buttons and javascript that trigger the popup modal

```
@ModelTYPE IEnumerable(of data_manager.attendance)

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascrip</script>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Conf. Number</th>
    <th>Class Title</th>
    <th>Status of Class</th>
    <td>Edit</td>
</tr>    
@For Each x In Model
    Dim currentItem = x
    @<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Function(f) currentItem.conf_number)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Function(f) currentItem.courseTitle)</td>
    @If currentItem.Completed_Class = "Completed" Then
        @<td>@Html.ActionLink("Completed(Print Cert)", "Ind_Cert", "Printing", New With {.firstName = currentItem.firstName, .lastname = currentItem.lastName, .classRef = currentItem.course_ref, .cNumber = currentItem.conf_number}, Nothing)</td>
    Else
        @<td>@Html.DisplayFor(Function(f) currentItem.Completed_Class)</td> 
    End If
    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Modify", "CourseHistoryEdit", New With {.id = currentItem.id}, New With {.class = "editLink"})</td>
    </tr>
Next
</table>
<div id="updateDialog" title="Update Attendance"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var linkObj;
$(function () {
    $(".editLink").button();
    $('#updateDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Update": function () {
                $("#update-message").html(''); //make sure there is nothing on the message before we continue                         
                $("#updateAttendance").submit();
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
    $(".editLink").click(function () {
        //change the title of the dialgo
        linkObj = $(this);
        var dialogDiv = $('#updateDialog');
        var viewUrl = linkObj.attr('href');
        $.get(viewUrl, function (data) {
            dialogDiv.html(data);
            //validation
            var $form = $("#updateAttendance");
            // Unbind existing validation
            $form.unbind();
            $form.data("validator", null);
            // Check document for changes
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);
            // Re add validation with changes
            $form.validate($form.data("unobtrusiveValidation").options);
            //open dialog
            dialogDiv.dialog('open');
        });
        return false;
    });
});

function updateSuccess(data) {
    if (data.Success == true) {
        //we update the table's info
        var parent = linkObj.closest("tr");
        parent.find(".Completed_Class").html(data.Object.completed);
        parent.find(".carDescription").html(data.Object.Description);
        //now we can close the dialog
        $('#updateDialog').dialog('close');
        //twitter type notification
        $('#commonMessage').html("Update Complete");
        $('#commonMessage').delay(400).slideDown(400).delay(3000).slideUp(400);
    }
    else {
        $("#update-message").html(data.ErrorMessage);
        $("#update-message").show();
    }
}
</script>
```

And this is the partialView that is rendered when the Modify button is clicked next to each one.

```
   @ModelTYPE DataModels.DataModels.AjaxCourseHistoryEdit

   @Using (Ajax.BeginForm("CourseHistoryEdit", "Admin", Nothing, New AjaxOptions With {.InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, .HttpMethod = "POST", .OnSuccess = "updateSuccess"}, New With {.id = "updateAttendance"}))
   @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

   @<fieldset>
   <legend>Attendance Update</legend>
   @Html.HiddenFor(Function(m) Model.attendId) 
   <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.Label("Course Title")
   </div>
   <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) Model.courseTitle)
   </div>
   <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.Label("Completed Status")
   </div>
   <div class="editor-field">
     @Html.DropDownList("completed", New SelectList(ViewBag.CourseStatuses))
   </div>
   <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.Label("Hours Completed")
   </div>
   <div>
    @Html.EditorFor(Function(m) Model.hoursCompleted)
   </div>
   </fieldset>    
   End Using
```

Below are the javascript libraries that are being loaded in the _layout file for the project.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript">     </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I have went around with this for hours and google searches have turned up several SO posts saying that `Unexpected token u` is related to an invalid line termination. This helps me none as I cannot find anything that remotely looks like improper html namely tags that arent closed..

I had a csharper bring up the `@` on the table and fieldset. This is normal in these instances for vb.net below is a screenshot of the rendered html
[image]

Comment: if i take the `@` off that tag the for each method there no longer will work correctly to build the table list.

Comment: When you submit your form, the values are being parsed into Json and that's where it goes wrong. When you call .serializeObject() on a form, it tries to generated a javascript object like this: { "input1" : "value1", "input2" : "value2", ... }

My guess would be: check if every input, textarea, select tag have "name" attributes and if their values would be serializable.

Comment: Please excuse me for asking this but is there a way to look at what is being output?

Comment: Sure. From your screenshot I can see you are using Google Chrome. (This is excellent) If you click on the left hand side of the screen at the line of the parseJSON function, you can set a breakpoint. This means that when you reload the page, the execution of the script will pause and you will be given the opportunity to check the value of "data". More info available here: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: Interesting to note is that you can open the Chrome Console *while* debugging and you can enter custom commands to try out some ideas. This is a very effective and fast way of looking for a solution in Javascript.

Comment: As a bit of curiosity and for a quick test I commented basically all lines of html code out under the fieldset and sure enough the submit button now submits to the controller. While there is no data to submit because i commented all that out it does mean that I am missing a name or something else. As you mentioned though. I did put a break there and data is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comment made by Moeri pointed me in the right direction. It turned out that my model was using a integer value for the hiddenFor value. Which for reasons unknown to me the AJAX post did not like that at all. By changing the type of `attendId` from `Integer` to `String` and further using proper `editorFor` / `labelFor` the issue has been resolved. Maybe this will help someone that hits this stumbling block as I have.

Comment: I had a similar issue when I left out a `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Field)` on one of my required inputs.  [Found it here](http://geekswithblogs.net/Aligned/archive/2013/05/20/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-u.-file-javascript-error-in-mvc.aspx).  Once I added the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Field)` for each required / non nullable fields, the error went away.